# How to navigate to a specific section of the page on page load using React Router?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have added BrowserRouter to my React App

```
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App/>}/>
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

This is how my App looks like:

```
<div className="App">
  <NavBar/>
  <Home/>
  <Contact/>
</div>
```

and my component looks like this:

```
 <div id="contact" className="Contact"/>
```

When I try to navigate directly to contact section of my page by using the link "mySite.com/#contact" it does not navigate. Can you help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: You need to specify rest of links:
     <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />

Comment: Thanks @CptSosen This did not work for me as Contact component is inside App component, but I was able to solve the issue using `scrollIntoView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using react lifecycle and `scrollIntoView`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const urlHash = window.location.hash;
    if (urlHash.length) {
      const element = document.getElementById(urlHash.substring(1));
      if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  }
```